# align right-to-left text with QPainter::drawText

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to paint a right-to-left text with `QPainter`. It however still aligns the text to left despite the fact that it should be right-aligned. Or at least it is right-aligned when displayed in `QTextEdit`. That am I doing wrong? See the example:

```
QTextOption option;
option.setTextDirection(Qt::LayoutDirectionAuto);
painter->drawText(rect, "خامل\nخاملخامل", option); // this is just testing text, I have no idea what it means, hopefully it is not something offensive :)
```

This is what I get. The red arrow shows where it should be aligned.

[image]

Of course I cannot use fixed right alignment because I do not whether the text in question is left-to-right or right-to-left text. So it must work for both directions automatically depending on the text.

UPDATE: I want to emphasize that I need a solution which automatically recognizes the language/writing system of the text (left-to-right, such as English, versus right-to-left, such as Arabic) and aligns the text automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check your text with `isRightToLeft()` function.

QString [isRightToLeft()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#isRightToLeft):

> Returns true if the string is read right to left.

This will help you to understand your text language.

I checked the `QTextEdit` source and understand it uses this function.

```
void  MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter  painter(this);

    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    QRect  rect  = QRect(0, 0, width(), height());

    QString  txt   = tr("خامل\nخاملخامل");
//    QString      txt = tr("ABCD\nABCD");
    QTextOption  option;

    if (txt.isRightToLeft())
    {
        option.setTextDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
    }
    else
    {
        option.setTextDirection(Qt::LeftToRight);
    }

    painter.drawText(rect, txt, option);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! I did not know about this function. It seems to work well. Thanks. And yes, I should have checked the `QTextEdit` code myself. But if I did, I would not ask and this question and this knowledge would not be available on StackOverflow. So my lack of activity brought lots of good for humanity this time. Thanks. :)